# Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.example. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-storage

My problem is that when i want to press the button it should show the image from firebase. But every time the app crashes with this error **"Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.example. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first."**

Her's my **Main Activity**

```
package com.nktschmitt.trailercheck

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import java.io.File
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp as initializeApp1

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)


        button.setOnClickListener {

            val image: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.rImage)
            val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("image/a.jpg")

            val localfile = File.createTempFile("tempImage", "jpg")
            storageRef.getFile(localfile).addOnSuccessListener {

                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localfile.absolutePath)
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

            }.addOnFailureListener {


                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Her's my **Project Gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.21"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.9'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Her's my **App Gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nktschmitt.trailercheck"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Google services plugin **v4.3.9** has this bug. [A newer plugin version](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#august_09_2021) is available with the fix. Please manually upgrade `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.9'` to  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'` in your project-level build.gradle file.

Comment: @Noah If the answer works then you should mark that as an answer so It will help future visitors and the community in general.

Comment: I'm on 4.3.10 and it's still doing it :(

Comment: its still happening

Answer (score 1):

i think still have bug 4.3.8, 4.3.9 , 4.3.10.

recommend downgrade 4.3.7

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30648281)

Answer (score 0):

1. The best solution for this error is to **update your AGP to 7.4.2(recommended) or higher**.

**OR**

2. If then also you are facing the same issue, then **update your Android studio version to latest version.**

***After this steps I have successfully remove the error.***